# Why is my KendoUI Grid with MultiSelect list crashing with a "... status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

In my ASP.net MVC application I've a Kendo UI Grid with a MultiSelect list. What I'm trying to do is to filter the grid based on the selections made in the MultiSelect list, but my view is crashing with the following error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Here is my code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
                 .Name("filter")
                 .DataValueField("SkillID")
                 .DataTextField("SkillName")
                 .Placeholder("Select Skills")
                 .Events(e => e.Change("onChange"))
                 .AutoBind(false)                                   
                 .DataSource(source =>
                    {
                      source.Read(read =>
                            {
                              read.Action("GetSkills", "Home");
                           })
                 .ServerFiltering(true);
                })
          )


@(Html.Kendo().Grid(
  (IEnumerable<BugFree.ViewModels.TechSkillViewModel>)ViewBag.TechSkills)
        .Name("grid1")
        .Columns(columns =>
            {
               columns.Bound(technician =>    
                  technician.UserID).Filterable(false);
               columns.Bound(technician => 
                   technician.FirstName).Filterable(false);
               })
          .Pageable()
          .Sortable()
          .Filterable()
          .DataSource(datasource => datasource
                  .Ajax()
                  .PageSize(20)                                  
                  .ServerOperation(false)
                  .Read(read => read.Action("GetTechnicians", "Home").Data("additionalData"))
       )
     )

<script>
function additionalData(e) {
    var value = $("#filter").data("kendoMultiSelect").value();
    alert(value);
    return { filter: value }; // send the filter value as part of the Read request
}

function onChange() {
    var grid = $("#grid1").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.dataSource.read(); // rebind the Grid's DataSource
}
```

And here is the controller code:

```
public ActionResult GetTechnicians(string filter, [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request )
    {   
        // Do the filtering here

        return Json(technicians, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Did you check in fiddler? what is happening when the call is made and what result is returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting a 500 (internal server error) because my controller was getting a null from the client. Turns out to be that since I'm using a MultiSelectList, Kendo UI sends a string array, while in my controller I had a string parameter, instead of string[]. Changing the type solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try switch the parameters order in controller to:

```
public ActionResult GetTechnicians([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string filter)
```

edit:
we also do this

```
return Json(customers.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried both with same result.

Comment: how about the ToDataSourceResult extension ? see my edit.

Comment: Nope. Same result. The error is for POST request. I'm not sure about the javascript method binding "onChange" and "additionalData".

Comment: Upon further investigation, server is throwing following exception: Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Somehow the selection made is not getting passed to the server.